# Facebook Playable Preview tool zip error?

Tags: facebook, phaser-framework

[screenShot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14OEp.png)
I am trying to make a Facebook playable ad in phaser3 but when I upload my zip file which is 101 kb. it is showing error File size must be less than 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

The 2MB size limit is on the index.html, not the zip file. Check the specs here: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/412951382532338

Comment: thankyou @PhotonStorm, but I wanted to preview my game using the Facebook playable-preview tool [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/playable-preview/) but getting an error while uploading zip file (and it is not larger than 5MB as specified in the Specifications for playable ads assets link provided by you)

Comment: The specification is split into two parts: First, the index.html (and any scripts it includes) cannot be more than 2MB. This is the part your game fails on. Your index is too large. Second, the WHOLE game, including all assets, must be less than 5MB. I.e. the whole game unzipped must be < 5MB AND the index + JS must be < 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to make too, it worked when I uploaded a really small tiny game that is not zipped.
I think there is an error in the Facebook preview because when I uploaded it using suit manager, it showed me the result.